# How to Shade Tikz Arc Just as I Did to Circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, arc

I want this `arc` shaded just like I did to the `Circle`.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    % Static part
        \draw[draw=white,fill=YellowOrange,thick] (-45:2.5) -- (-45:4) arc(-45:-90:4) -- (-90:2.5) arc(-90:-45:2.5) -- cycle ;
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10] (1.5,-3.7) circle (0.2cm);{\tiny (3.8,-1.4) circle (0.2cm);}
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = YellowOrange] (1.5,-3.7) circle (0.1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is [image: its output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to be a smart aleck but you want the arc to be shaded like the circle. Here is it:

[image: shaded arc]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    % Static part
        \draw[draw=white,shading=ball, ball color = YellowOrange,thick] (-45:2.5) -- (-45:4) arc(-45:-90:4) -- (-90:2.5) arc(-90:-45:2.5) -- cycle ;
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10] (1.5,-3.7) circle (0.2cm);{\tiny (3.8,-1.4) circle (0.2cm);}
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = YellowOrange] (1.5,-3.7) circle (0.1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```